# problem in updating MongoDB time series document. It creates a new record instead of updating the existing one

Tags: mongodb, debezium

I have replicated a PostgreSQL partitioned table in a MongoDB time series collection using debezium and Kafka mongodb sink connector. when I update a record in the PostgreSQL table I expect that the same record is updated in MongoDB collection but instead a new record is created in MongoDB table.

according to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.6/sink-connector/configuration-properties/all-properties/#write-model-strategy) if you set the timeseries.timefield option in the connector configs, the "InsertOneDefaultStrategy" write model will be applied which inserts each sink record into MongoDB as a document. Is there a way to change this behavior?